# Slow conversion of VDMK to VDI - Virtual Machine Converter 3.1

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, virtual-machines, hyper-v, vmware-vsphere

So I am trying to migrate from VMWare to Hyper-V and I'm using the MS tool Virtual Machine Converter 3.1.

However, the VM conversions are going super slow.  Like 2MB a second which means that a 300GB machine would take 34 hours to convert.  Any idea why this is so slow?  Is there a quicker method I could use?

I looked at the VMDK's and there is about 3 or 4 per VM based off of partitions so I'm unsure how to use the powershell command which I think is simpler

This is the powershell command but there are multiple VDMK's per VM.

*ConvertTo-MvmcVirtualHardDisk -SourceLiteralPath d:\scratch\vmx\VM-disk1.vmdk -VhdType DynamicHardDisk -VhdFormat vhdx -destination c:\vm-disk1*

Thoughts?

Comment: QoS of the NIC on ? on a 1G conenction it use 100mbps max in a transfert like that if QoS is on.

Comment: You could try Disk2VHD or Starwind V2V Converter. - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 - https://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter

Comment: I haven't found Microsoft documentation on this yet, but I'm pretty sure the potential bottlenecks are network connection between the ESX and Hyper-V servers in question (as yagmoth555 suggests), converting machine computing power, and temporary conversion storage performance. Also it is not a fast process in general. We have a pretty robust setup and it takes about an hour per 100 GB for us. Obviously yours could be faster, but it's unlikely to be just a few minutes.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I'll have to take a look at the QoS

Comment: @joeqwerty I looked into starwind, I'll give that a go.  However, I'm a little confused becasue there's multiple VDMK's per machine.  I'm curious do I just use the VDMX?

Comment: I'll be honest, I've not found this to be the best tool, I've had much better success with some of the paid tools.

Comment: @MartynC which tools?

Comment: Sorry @tjcinnamon thought I had added them. I have great success with DoubleTake for both on-premises and cloud migrations and actually using Azure ASR for cloud migrations

Comment: Hi All, 
I'll give this a try this weekend and give you a response.